# Older ca-certificates.crt gets copied between stages in multi-stage Dockerfile

Tags: ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I have a multi-stage Dockerfile of this format where I am trying to add a self generated CA cert to the docker image.

```
FROM golang:1.13 as builder
RUN cp myCA.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates

# Few more lines here that copy some files I cannot mention

FROM docker.io/alpine@sha256:a15790640a6690aa1730c38cf0a440e2aa44aaca9b0e8931a9f2b0d7cc90fd65 

COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# Entrypoint command that I cannot mention
```

What I noticed is that when I start the docker container based on the built image and exec into it, and curl an https endpoint whose certificate is signed by myCA.crt, I get

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

But I was not expecting to get this because while building the image, I do see that the CA cert is getting added to the trusted list of CA certificates

```
Step 6/20 : RUN update-ca-certificates
 ---> Running in af768d679d17
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
1 added, 0 removed; done.
```

Further, I troubleshooted and confirmed that the CA cert indicated was not to be found in ca-certificates.crt of the built image at all.

I also started a docker container for the image `golang:1.13` and repeated the steps to add the CA cert indicated, and I was able to curl the same endpoint without any error.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying the myCA.crt to the second stage of the Dockerfile and running update-ca-certificates

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/myCA.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/myCA.crt
RUN apk add ca-certificates && apk update && update-ca-certificates
```

and the CA cert got updated in ca-certificates.crt